# Вывод изображения из Mysql в QLabel

Tags: python, pyqt5, qlabel, pymysql, qpixmap

В окне авторизации данные заполняются пользователем отправляются в БД.
После введения данных и нажатия кнопки "Продолжить" генерируется тест содержащий картинки, вопросы и ответы. В БД хранятся изображения, при запросе выводится кодировка, а не изображение, как можно вывести изображение?

Может есть варианты обойтись без добавления изображения в БД, то как добиться генерации теста с выводом картинки и вопроса с ответами?

**main.py**:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QLabel, QLineEdit, QGridLayout, QMessageBox)
from titul import Ui_mainWindow
from login import Ui_Login
from test import Ui_Test
from Leksia import Ui_Leksia
import pymysql
import random
from config import host, user, password, db_name

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_mainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.connection = pymysql.connect(
            host=host,
            port=3306,
            user=user,
            password=password,
            database=db_name,
            cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor
        )
        self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()

        self.Button_startTest.clicked.connect(self.openLogin)
        self.Button_runLR.clicked.connect(self.openLeksia)

    def openLeksia(self):
        self.leksia = LeksiaWindow()
        self.close()
        self.leksia.show()

    def openLogin(self):
        self.login = LoginWindow(self.connection)
        self.close()
        self.login.show()


class LeksiaWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_Leksia):
    def __init__(self):
        super(LeksiaWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.returnToMain)

    def returnToMain(self):
        self.close()
        w.show()


class TestWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_Test):
    def __init__(self):
        super(TestWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)



class LoginWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_Login):
    def __init__(self, connection):
        super(LoginWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.connection = connection
        self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()
        
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.check_password)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.testImage)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.testText)
        

    def opentest(self):
        self.fio = self.lineEdit_2.text()
        self.grupp = self.lineEdit_3.text()
        self.cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO students (ФИО, Номер_группы) VALUES ('{self.fio}', '{self.grupp}')")
        self.connection.commit()

        self.test = TestWindow()

        self.close()
        self.test.show()

    def check_password(self):
            self.fio = self.lineEdit_2.text()
            self.grupp = self.lineEdit_3.text()
            if not self.fio or not self.grupp:    
                msg = QMessageBox.information(
                    self, 
                    'Внимание', 
                    'Введите данные для авторизации.'
                )
                return            
            elif self.fio != self.lineEdit_2.text() or self.grupp != self.lineEdit_3.text():    
                msg = QMessageBox.information(
                    self, 
                )              
                return     

            self.opentest()     

    
    def testText(self):
        mas = random.sample(range(1, 9), 2)
        a = mas[0]
        b = mas[1]

        print(a, b)

        a1 = "SELECT VoprosImage FROM bddiplom.test WHERE id =" + str(a) + ";"
        b1 = "SELECT VoprosImage FROM bddiplom.test WHERE id =" + str(b) + ";"

        a11 = "SELECT VoprosText FROM bddiplom.test WHERE id =" + str(a) + ";"
        b11 = "SELECT VoprosText FROM bddiplom.test WHERE id =" + str(b) + ";"
        

        mas1 = random.sample(range(1, 5), 4)
        k_1 = mas1[0]
        l_1 = mas1[1]
        m_1 = mas1[2]
        n_1 = mas1[3]
        print(k_1, l_1, m_1, n_1)

        mas2 = random.sample(range(1, 5), 4)
        k_2 = mas2[0]
        l_2 = mas2[1]
        m_2 = mas2[2]
        n_2 = mas2[3]
        print(k_2, l_2, m_2, n_2)

        k1 = "SELECT otv1 FROM bddiplom.test WHERE id =" + str(a) + ";"
        l1 = "SELECT otv2 FROM bddiplom.test WHERE id =" + str(a) + ";"
        m1 = "SELECT otv3 FROM bddiplom.test WHERE id =" + str(a) + ";"
        n1 = "SELECT otv4 FROM bddiplom.test WHERE id =" + str(a) + ";"

        k2 = "SELECT otv1 FROM bddiplom.test WHERE id =" + str(b) + ";"
        l2 = "SELECT otv2 FROM bddiplom.test WHERE id =" + str(b) + ";"
        m2 = "SELECT otv3 FROM bddiplom.test WHERE id =" + str(b) + ";"
        n2 = "SELECT otv4 FROM bddiplom.test WHERE id =" + str(b) + ";"


        with self.connection.cursor() as cursor:
            cursor.execute(a1)
            result = cursor.fetchone()
            a2 = result['VoprosImage']
            self.test.label_2.setText(str(a2))

            cursor.execute(b1)
            result = cursor.fetchone()
            b2 = result['VoprosImage']
            self.test.label_4.setText(str(b2))

            cursor.execute(a11)
            result = cursor.fetchone()
            a22 = result['VoprosText']
            self.test.textEdit_4.setText(str(a22))
            
            cursor.execute(b11)
            result = cursor.fetchone()
            b22 = result['VoprosText']
            self.test.textEdit_5.setText(str(b22))

            self.test.comboBox.addItem(""); self.test.comboBox.addItem(""); self.test.comboBox.addItem(""); self.test.comboBox.addItem("")
            self.test.comboBox_2.addItem(""); self.test.comboBox_2.addItem(""); self.test.comboBox_2.addItem(""); self.test.comboBox_2.addItem("")
        
        #Вопрос 1
            cursor.execute(k1)
            result = cursor.fetchone()
            kk1 = result['otv1']
            self.test.comboBox.setItemText(k_1, str(kk1))

            cursor.execute(l1)
            result = cursor.fetchone()
            ll1 = result['otv2']
            self.test.comboBox.setItemText(l_1, str(ll1))

            cursor.execute(m1)
            result = cursor.fetchone()
            mm1 = result['otv3']
            self.test.comboBox.setItemText(m_1, str(mm1))

            cursor.execute(n1)
            result = cursor.fetchone()
            nn1 = result['otv4']
            self.test.comboBox.setItemText(n_1, str(nn1))

        #Вопрос 2
            cursor.execute(k2)
            result = cursor.fetchone()
            kk2 = result['otv1']
            self.test.comboBox_2.setItemText(k_2, str(kk2))

            cursor.execute(l2)
            result = cursor.fetchone()
            ll2 = result['otv2']
            self.test.comboBox_2.setItemText(l_2, str(ll2))

            cursor.execute(m2)
            result = cursor.fetchone()
            mm2 = result['otv3']
            self.test.comboBox_2.setItemText(m_2, str(mm2))

            cursor.execute(n2)
            result = cursor.fetchone()
            nn2 = result['otv4']
            self.test.comboBox_2.setItemText(n_2, str(nn2))


    def testImage(self):
        mas = random.sample(range(9, 21), 3)
        a = mas[0]
        b = mas[1]
        c = mas[2]
        print(a, b, c)

        
        a1 = "SELECT VoprosText FROM bddiplom.test WHERE id =" + str(a) + ";"
        b1 = "SELECT VoprosText FROM bddiplom.test WHERE id =" + str(b) + ";"
        c1 = "SELECT VoprosText FROM bddiplom.test WHERE id =" + str(c) + ";"
        

        mas1 = random.sample(range(1, 5), 4)
        k_1 = mas1[0]
        l_1 = mas1[1]
        m_1 = mas1[2]
        n_1 = mas1[3]
        print(k_1, l_1, m_1, n_1)

        mas2 = random.sample(range(1, 5), 4)
        k_2 = mas2[0]
        l_2 = mas2[1]
        m_2 = mas2[2]
        n_2 = mas2[3]
        print(k_2, l_2, m_2, n_2)

        mas3 = random.sample(range(1, 5), 4)
        k_3 = mas3[0]
        l_3 = mas3[1]
        m_3 = mas3[2]
        n_3 = mas3[3]
        print(k_3, l_3, m_3, n_3)


        k1 = "SELECT otv1 FROM bddiplom.test WHERE id =" + str(a) + ";"
        l1 = "SELECT otv2 FROM bddiplom.test WHERE id =" + str(a) + ";"
        m1 = "SELECT otv3 FROM bddiplom.test WHERE id =" + str(a) + ";"
        n1 = "SELECT otv4 FROM bddiplom.test WHERE id =" + str(a) + ";"

        k2 = "SELECT otv1 FROM bddiplom.test WHERE id =" + str(b) + ";"
        l2 = "SELECT otv2 FROM bddiplom.test WHERE id =" + str(b) + ";"
        m2 = "SELECT otv3 FROM bddiplom.test WHERE id =" + str(b) + ";"
        n2 = "SELECT otv4 FROM bddiplom.test WHERE id =" + str(b) + ";"

        
        k3 = "SELECT otv1 FROM bddiplom.test WHERE  id =" + str(c) + ";"
        l3 = "SELECT otv2 FROM bddiplom.test WHERE  id =" + str(c) + ";"
        m3 = "SELECT otv3 FROM bddiplom.test WHERE  id =" + str(c) + ";"
        n3 = "SELECT otv4 FROM bddiplom.test WHERE  id =" + str(c) + ";"


        with self.connection.cursor() as cursor:
            cursor.execute(a1)
            result = cursor.fetchone()
            a2 = result['VoprosText']
            self.test.textEdit.setText(str(a2))

            cursor.execute(b1)
            result = cursor.fetchone()
            b2 = result['VoprosText']
            self.test.textEdit_2.setText(str(b2))

            cursor.execute(c1)
            result = cursor.fetchone()
            c2 = result['VoprosText']
            self.test.textEdit_3.setText(str(c2))


            self.test.comboBox_3.addItem(""); self.test.comboBox_3.addItem(""); self.test.comboBox_3.addItem(""); self.test.comboBox_3.addItem("")
            self.test.comboBox_4.addItem(""); self.test.comboBox_4.addItem(""); self.test.comboBox_4.addItem(""); self.test.comboBox_4.addItem("")
            self.test.comboBox_5.addItem(""); self.test.comboBox_5.addItem(""); self.test.comboBox_5.addItem(""); self.test.comboBox_5.addItem("")
        
        #Вопрос 1
            cursor.execute(k1)
            result = cursor.fetchone()
            kk1 = result['otv1']
            self.test.comboBox_3.setItemText(k_1, str(kk1))

            cursor.execute(l1)
            result = cursor.fetchone()
            ll1 = result['otv2']
            self.test.comboBox_3.setItemText(l_1, str(ll1))

            cursor.execute(m1)
            result = cursor.fetchone()
            mm1 = result['otv3']
            self.test.comboBox_3.setItemText(m_1, str(mm1))

            cursor.execute(n1)
            result = cursor.fetchone()
            nn1 = result['otv4']
            self.test.comboBox_3.setItemText(n_1, str(nn1))

        #Вопрос 2
            cursor.execute(k2)
            result = cursor.fetchone()
            kk2 = result['otv1']
            self.test.comboBox_4.setItemText(k_2, str(kk2))

            cursor.execute(l2)
            result = cursor.fetchone()
            ll2 = result['otv2']
            self.test.comboBox_4.setItemText(l_2, str(ll2))

            cursor.execute(m2)
            result = cursor.fetchone()
            mm2 = result['otv3']
            self.test.comboBox_4.setItemText(m_2, str(mm2))

            cursor.execute(n2)
            result = cursor.fetchone()
            nn2 = result['otv4']
            self.test.comboBox_4.setItemText(n_2, str(nn2))

        #Вопрос 3
            cursor.execute(k3)
            result = cursor.fetchone()
            kk3 = result['otv1']
            self.test.comboBox_5.setItemText(k_3, str(kk3))

            cursor.execute(l3)
            result = cursor.fetchone()
            ll3 = result['otv2']
            self.test.comboBox_5.setItemText(l_3, str(ll3))

            cursor.execute(m3)
            result = cursor.fetchone()
            mm3 = result['otv3']
            self.test.comboBox_5.setItemText(m_3, str(mm3))

            cursor.execute(n3)
            result = cursor.fetchone()
            nn3 = result['otv4']
            self.test.comboBox_5.setItemText(n_3, str(nn3))



if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**login.py:**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets



class Ui_Login(object):
    def setupUi(self, Login):
        Login.setObjectName("Login")
        Login.resize(1100, 800)
        Login.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(Login)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(280, 120, 581, 41))
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Maximum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Maximum)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.label.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.label.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(198, 212, 255);")
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(490, 440, 141, 71))
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.pushButton.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.pushButton.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(198, 212, 255);")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(480, 310, 141, 31))
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Maximum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Maximum)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.label_3.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.label_3.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.label_3.setFont(font)
        self.label_3.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(198, 212, 255);")
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(520, 190, 61, 41))
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Maximum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Maximum)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.label_2.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.label_2.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(198, 212, 255);")
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(380, 260, 331, 31))
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.lineEdit_2.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.lineEdit_2.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        self.lineEdit_3 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(380, 360, 331, 31))
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.lineEdit_3.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.lineEdit_3.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.lineEdit_3.setObjectName("lineEdit_3")
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(-4, -8, 1111, 811))
        self.label_4.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.label_4.setText("")
        self.label_4.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("images2.jpg"))
        self.label_4.setScaledContents(True)
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.label_4.raise_()
        self.label.raise_()
        self.pushButton.raise_()
        self.label_3.raise_()
        self.label_2.raise_()
        self.lineEdit_2.raise_()
        self.lineEdit_3.raise_()
        Login.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(Login)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Login)




    def retranslateUi(self, Login):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Login.setWindowTitle(_translate("Login", "Авторизация"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Login", "<html><head/><body><p align=\"center\"><span style=\" font-size:14pt;\">Для прохождения теста необходимо заполнить ФИО и номер группы</span></p></body></html>"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Login", "Продолжить"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("Login", "<html><head/><body><p align=\"center\"><span style=\" font-size:14pt;\">Номер группы</span></p></body></html>"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("Login", "<html><head/><body><p align=\"center\"><span style=\" font-size:14pt;\">ФИО</span></p></body></html>"))
```

**test.py:**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_Test(object):
    def setupUi(self, Test):
        Test.setObjectName("Test")
        Test.resize(1100, 800)
        Test.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(Test)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.tabWidget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tabWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1111, 761))
        self.tabWidget.setObjectName("tabWidget")
        self.tab = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab.setObjectName("tab")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 0, 81, 16))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.tab)
        self.comboBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 310, 621, 22))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.comboBox.setFont(font)
        self.comboBox.setObjectName("comboBox")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 60, 621, 241))
        self.label_2.setText("")
        self.label_2.setScaledContents(True)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 430, 611, 281))
        self.label_4.setText("")
        self.label_4.setScaledContents(True)
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 350, 81, 16))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.label_3.setFont(font)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.comboBox_2 = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.tab)
        self.comboBox_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 710, 631, 22))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.comboBox_2.setFont(font)
        self.comboBox_2.setObjectName("comboBox_2")
        self.comboBox_2.addItem("")
        self.textEdit_4 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.tab)
        self.textEdit_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 20, 1081, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.textEdit_4.setFont(font)
        self.textEdit_4.setObjectName("textEdit_4")
        self.textEdit_5 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.tab)
        self.textEdit_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 380, 1081, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.textEdit_5.setFont(font)
        self.textEdit_5.setObjectName("textEdit_5")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab, "")
        self.tab_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab_2.setObjectName("tab_2")
        self.comboBox_3 = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.tab_2)
        self.comboBox_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 150, 971, 22))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.comboBox_3.setFont(font)
        self.comboBox_3.setObjectName("comboBox_3")
        self.comboBox_3.addItem("")
        self.label_6 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab_2)
        self.label_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 10, 81, 16))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.label_6.setFont(font)
        self.label_6.setObjectName("label_6")
        self.comboBox_4 = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.tab_2)
        self.comboBox_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 330, 971, 22))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.comboBox_4.setFont(font)
        self.comboBox_4.setObjectName("comboBox_4")
        self.comboBox_4.addItem("")
        self.label_7 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab_2)
        self.label_7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 190, 81, 16))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.label_7.setFont(font)
        self.label_7.setObjectName("label_7")
        self.comboBox_5 = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.tab_2)
        self.comboBox_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 530, 971, 22))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.comboBox_5.setFont(font)
        self.comboBox_5.setObjectName("comboBox_5")
        self.comboBox_5.addItem("")
        self.label_8 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab_2)
        self.label_8.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 390, 81, 16))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.label_8.setFont(font)
        self.label_8.setObjectName("label_8")
        self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.tab_2)
        self.textEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 30, 971, 121))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.textEdit.setFont(font)
        self.textEdit.setObjectName("textEdit")
        self.textEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.tab_2)
        self.textEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 210, 971, 121))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.textEdit_2.setFont(font)
        self.textEdit_2.setObjectName("textEdit_2")
        self.textEdit_3 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.tab_2)
        self.textEdit_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 410, 971, 121))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.textEdit_3.setFont(font)
        self.textEdit_3.setObjectName("textEdit_3")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_2, "")
        self.pushButtonEndTest = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButtonEndTest.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(880, 760, 211, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.pushButtonEndTest.setFont(font)
        self.pushButtonEndTest.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(212, 212, 212);")
        self.pushButtonEndTest.setObjectName("pushButtonEndTest")
        Test.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(Test)
        self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Test)

    def retranslateUi(self, Test):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Test.setWindowTitle(_translate("Test", "Тест"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Test", "Вопрос 1"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(0, _translate("Test", "..."))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("Test", "Вопрос 2"))
        self.comboBox_2.setItemText(0, _translate("Test", "..."))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab), _translate("Test", "Вопросы с картинкой"))
        self.comboBox_3.setItemText(0, _translate("Test", "..."))
        self.label_6.setText(_translate("Test", "Вопрос 3"))
        self.comboBox_4.setItemText(0, _translate("Test", "..."))
        self.label_7.setText(_translate("Test", "Вопрос 4"))
        self.comboBox_5.setItemText(0, _translate("Test", "..."))
        self.label_8.setText(_translate("Test", "Вопрос 5"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_2), _translate("Test", "Текстовые вопросы"))
        self.pushButtonEndTest.setText(_translate("Test", "Закончить тест"))
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Comment: Хранить файлы в виде блоб полей - изначально отвратительная идея.

Comment: Два варианта. Первый - на MySQL конвертить в текст (скажем, Base64), на клиенте обратно и затем показывать. Второй - на MySQL сохранять в файл, на клиенте ссылаться на него.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Я не могу проверить ваш пример.
2. Вам надо научиться создавать минимально-воспроизводимые примеры, которые демонстрируют только вашу текущую проблему, а не публиковать ваш полный проект, который вы уже не можете разместить в вопросе (я не увидел модуль **titul.py**).

---

> bool QPixmap::[**loadFromData**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpixmap.html#loadFromData)(const uchar *data, uint len, const char *format = nullptr, Qt::ImageConversionFlags flags = Qt::AutoColor)
>
> Загружает растровое изображение из len первых байтов заданных двоичных данных. Возвращает true, если растровое изображение было успешно загружено; в противном случае делает растровое изображение недействительным и возвращает false.
>
> Загрузчик пытается прочитать растровое изображение, используя указанный формат. Если формат не указан (это значение по умолчанию), загрузчик проверяет файл на наличие заголовка, чтобы угадать формат файла.
>
> Если данные необходимо изменить, чтобы они соответствовали результату с более низким разрешением (например, преобразование из 32-битного в 8-битное), используйте флаги для управления преобразованием.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Demo(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        

#        a2 = result['VoprosImage']   # это данные из BLOB
        a2 = b'\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n\x00\x00\x00\rIHDR\x00\x00\x00\x18\x00\x00\x00\x18\x08\x03\x00\x00\x00\xd7\xa9\xcd\xca\x00\x00\x00]PLTE\x00\x00\x00\x00\xca\xdf\x00\xce\xd8\x00\xc6\xd9\x00\xc8\xd6\x00\xc9\xd8\x00\xca\xd8\x00\xc9\xd6\x00\xc9\xd9\x00\xc8\xd8\x00\xc8\xd8\x00\xc9\xd8\x00\xc8\xd8\x00\xc8\xd7\x00\xc8\xd7\x00\xc8\xd7\x00\xc8\xd8\x1e\xce\xdc?\xd6\xe2F\xd8\xe3J\xd9\xe4M\xd9\xe4R\xdb\xe5\x80\xe4\xeb\x81\xe4\xec\xa7\xed\xf2\xc1\xf1\xf5\xe4\xf9\xfb\xe7\xfa\xfb\xe8\xfa\xfc\xff\xff\xff{k\xa3T\x00\x00\x00\x1etRNS\x00\x18\x1a\x1bJhi\x97\xb3\xd6\xd7\xef\xf0\xf1\xf9\xfb\xfc\xfc\xfc\xfc\xfc\xfc\xfc\xfd\xfd\xfd\xfe\xfe\xfe\xfe\xd4[\xd8`\x00\x00\x00\xbaIDAT(\xcfu\x92\x81\x0e\x83 \x0cD\xebT@\x14eN\'\x1b\x8e\xff\xffLA\xe8\xa81\\H\x08\xf7\xe4\xa8\x05\x80\xa8\x9a\x89N\r\x9d`5PU|\xd4I#\xaf\xb2\xdf\xf4\x9a\xa8o\xd0o\'}\xd1\xd4\xa6\xef\x93\xbfX\xbb$r\xee\xa90\xc7:g1-\x9c\xc3\xf5\x1dh\xee\xeb\xfc\xd7\x93\xa3|m5\xb00\xbf\x0c\xd1;8\x0cD\x98~\x8e\xe8\xcc\x13 q\xc77\x98\x9fu]\x9f\xc1\x91\xa00\xd6\x04`p\xa5J`\x88Qw\xd0\xc5\xc3#\xd8\xf7\x0cD,7\x02c2`\xf9\x07/`|\xe4\x96\\\x00\'M\xdc\xdc\xe6\x07i"\xb6}\xb6\xb3\x1f\xa4\xed\xe5\x8b*_m\xf91\xc4\xe7#\x95\x92\xf9\xf9\x1ckg\x1f\xd4\x9b\xe3\xb0\x8b\x00\x00\x00\x00IEND\xaeB`\x82'

        self.label = QLabel()
        pix = QPixmap()                                           # !!! +++
        rez = pix.loadFromData(a2)                                # !!! +++
        print(f'rez = {rez}\n') #

#        self.label.setText(str(a2))
        self.label.setPixmap(pix)                                 # !!! +++
        
        vbox = QVBoxLayout(self)
        vbox.addWidget(self.label)        
        
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Demo()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я подумал что понятна проблема и тот файл будет не нужен, тк он начальная страница, если он нужен могу добавить.  Как мне получить кодировку на a2 в mysql workbench?

Comment: @TigerShark лично для меня ничего добавлять не надо, а для других не знаю. Я же для вас отметил что вам надо поменять, вы проверили мои предложения?

Comment: Я так понял, вы советуете использовать qpixmap?

Comment: @TigerShark да, замените `self.test.label_2.setText(str(a2))` на три строки, которые я выделил. Только вместо `label` напишите `label_2`

Comment: Помогло, большое спасибо)

Comment: @TigerShark пожалуйста